# React doesn't render returned thing from async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function like this, this function aims to make a list of transactions and return them, everything is good on this function. There are no errors.

```js
        function ListTX() {
          (async () => {
          const arweave = Arweave.init();
          var address = window.sessionStorage.getItem("WalletAddress");
          const txids = await arweave.arql({
                op: 'and',
                expr1:
                {
                  op: 'equals',
                  expr1: 'from',
                  expr2: address
                },
                expr2:
                {
                  op: 'equals',
                  expr1: 'App-Name',
                  expr2: 'arshard'
                }
          })
          console.log(txids);
          const all_transactions = txids.map((transaction, idx) => {
              return <li key={idx}>{transaction}</li>;
          });
          console.log(all_transactions);
        return (
          <ul>
            {all_transactions}
          </ul>
          );
        })();
        }
```

Even though `all_transactions` is not empty, React doesn't render this. Same thing actually works with an normal function.

```js
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <main>
                    <article>
                {ListTX()}
                    </article>
                </main>
            </div>
        );
```

And here is full class:

```js
class Construct extends React.Component {
    render() {

        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("wallet")) {
        function ListTX() {
          (async () => {
          const arweave = Arweave.init();
          var address = window.sessionStorage.getItem("WalletAddress");
          const txids = await arweave.arql({
                op: 'and',
                expr1:
                {
                  op: 'equals',
                  expr1: 'from',
                  expr2: address
                },
                expr2:
                {
                  op: 'equals',
                  expr1: 'App-Name',
                  expr2: 'arshard'
                }
          })
          console.log(txids);
          const all_transactions = txids.map((transaction, idx) => {
              return <li key={idx}>{transaction}</li>;
          });
          console.log(all_transactions);
        })();
        return (
          <ul>
            {all_transactions}
          </ul>
          );
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <main>
                    <article>
                {ListTX()}
                    </article>
                </main>
            </div>
        );
      }
      else {
        return (<Redirect to="/upload_wallet"/>);
      }
    };
};
}
export default Construct;
```

And this is what `console.log(all_transactions)` returned:

```
[
  {
    "type": "li",
    "key": "0",
    "ref": null,
    "props": {
      "children": "QWCFEHGEa0Lf2zywL_nBYmnEXhG3hLqyFcxQykhJhAc"
    },
    "_owner": null,
    "_store": {}
  },
  {
    "type": "li",
    "key": "1",
    "ref": null,
    "props": {
      "children": "cbVaHaRayhOkXR0lLL_1KFNnbyP8EEAWVQIGSKxo_2Y"
    },
    "_owner": null,
    "_store": {}
  },
  {
    "type": "li",
    "key": "2",
    "ref": null,
    "props": {
      "children": "gOrpgD3cVNEzf-u2fqI4KI5G49qaBA9jMwq-VMiQp_Q"
    },
    "_owner": null,
    "_store": {}
  },
  {
    "type": "li",
    "key": "3",
    "ref": null,
    "props": {
      "children": "PYT3WoT5dtzhyxjCQ_2dn-8ZJCqEtfZBI4-RaWJCBks"
    },
    "_owner": null,
    "_store": {}
  },
  {
    "type": "li",
    "key": "4",
    "ref": null,
    "props": {
      "children": "HJymy5uP2sqTwX5nbbzuqEXMyXliwodpIgjT5s0puxI"
    },
    "_owner": null,
    "_store": {}
  }
]
```

It works if I do something like this

```js
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("wallet")) {
        function ListTX() {
          (async () => {
          const arweave = Arweave.init();
          var address = window.sessionStorage.getItem("WalletAddress");
          const txids = await arweave.arql({
                op: 'and',
                expr1:
                {
                  op: 'equals',
                  expr1: 'from',
                  expr2: address
                },
                expr2:
                {
                  op: 'equals',
                  expr1: 'App-Name',
                  expr2: 'arshard'
                }
          })
          console.log(txids);
          const all_transactions = txids.map((transaction, idx) => {
              return <li key={idx}>{transaction}</li>;
          });
          console.log(all_transactions);
        })();
        return (
          <p>
            test
          </p>
          );
        }
```

and test is written on the web page. That's why I suspect it is something related to async function, if I try to do same in the async it doesn't work.

What is the true way to render this list, inside our outside function `ListTX()`?

Comment: Should you not wait for async? you are missing `await`. Also, my suggestion is to split your logic as 1) Get Data (async). 2) Create JSX from data. Then once data is received, set it in state and it should work fine

Comment: I don't know if I should wait, but `await` doesn't works with `return();`

Comment: The render function should be a pure function based on state and props. Api calls and other things with side effects should not be inside of render. Fetch your transactions in one of the lifecycle methods (e.g., componentDidMount()) and then set the returned data in state.

Comment: `return` will return it. Since its an async function, there is a delayed return. So, `ListTX()` in normal context returns undefined. But if you ask your code to wait, it will get proper JSX. However, its not recomended.

Comment: Why would `ListTX()` return undefined? I tried the same with normal function _without list_ like `return(<p>test</p>);` and it did work.

Comment: @EvanMorrison Can you explain it inside an answer, please? How can I use `componentDidMount())` with this codebase?

Comment: I edited my comment and added extra explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a CodeSandbox showing how I would suggest structuring the component.

[image: Edit morning-firefly-xlvqo]

Basically as follows:

```
class Construct extends React.Component {
  state = {
    all_transactions: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("wallet")) {
      (async () => {
        const arweave = Arweave.init();
        var address = window.sessionStorage.getItem("WalletAddress");
        const txids = await arweave.arql({
          op: "and",
          expr1: {
            op: "equals",
            expr1: "from",
            expr2: address
          },
          expr2: {
            op: "equals",
            expr1: "App-Name",
            expr2: "arshard"
          }
        });
        console.log(txids);
        this.setState({ all_transactions: txids });
      })();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <main>
          <article>
            <ul>
              {this.state.all_transactions.map(tx => (
                <li key={tx.key}>{tx.props.children}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </article>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Construct;
```

Comment: `TypeError: tx.props is undefined` at `<li key={tx.key}>{tx.props.children}</li>`

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, in order to "say" to React to render some, you have to set the `state` component. So my suggestion is to store `all_transactions` into `state` like:

```
class Construct extends React.Component {
....
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state : {
    state_all_transactions: [];
  }

 // then when you retrieve all_transactions
 ...
 this.setState({state_all_transactions: all_transactions});
 ...
}
```

And on return:

```
return (
      <ul>
        {this.stete.state_all_transactions}
      </ul>
);
```

Try this, should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, I don't think that would work since anything returned from function doesn't work. For example even if I try to return `return(<p>test</p>);` inside `async` function it doesn't work.

Comment: Ciao, as @EvanMorrison suggested, try to change your code by retrieving state_all_transactions outside the render function (for example in componentDidMount()). Then, use my example and will work (I have done it several times)

Comment: Hey, I'm beginner to React, I didn't understand how to fully implement this to my code base. Can you show detailed code, please?

Answer (score 0):

you may re-write your code like this

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

function ListTX() {
  const arweave = Arweave.init();
  const [txids, setTxids] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getTxids()
  }, []);
  const getTxids = async() => {
    const address = window.sessionStorage.getItem("WalletAddress");
    const tx = await arweave.arql({
      op: 'and',
      expr1:
        {
          op: 'equals',
          expr1: 'from',
          expr2: address
        },
      expr2:
        {
          op: 'equals',
          expr1: 'App-Name',
          expr2: 'arshard'
        }
    });
    setTxids(tx);
  };
  const all_transactions = txids.map((transaction, idx) => {
    return <li key={idx}>{transaction}</li>;
  });
  console.log(all_transactions);
  return (
    <ul>
      {all_transactions}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

then use it as:

```
return (
    <div>
        <Header/>
        <main>
            <article>
                <ListTX/>
            </article>
        </main>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
`

Comment: @BeytullahBas this function is a function component and nothing is wrong in here